# Regex to read the following formatted string pattern

Tags: java, regex

I want to read and map the following formatted lines into java bean

```
80 : (1,53.38,€45) (2,88.62,€98) (3,78.48,€3) (4,72.30,€76) (5,30.18,€9)
7  : (1,10.02,€5) (2,8.2,€9) (3,7.8,€2) (4,7.0,€6) (5,3.18,€9)
```

So here the digit before : will be captured as a int value and will be mapped on totalWeight and repetive patterns like (1,53.38,€45) will be mapped to items

Here is my java bean

```
public class Package {

    private double maxWeigh; \\ so the digit value before : will be here

    private List<Product> products;  \\ (1,53.38,€45) will be parsed to product class

    public double getMaxWeigh() {
        return maxWeigh;
    }

    public void setMaxWeigh(double maxWeigh) {
        this.maxWeigh = maxWeigh;
    }

    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public void setProducts(List<Product> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }
}
```

Here is my product class

```
public class Product {

    private int index;

    private double weight;

    private double cost;

    private String currencySymbol;

    public double getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(double weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public double getCost() {
        return cost;
    }

    public void setCost(double cost) {
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    public String getCurrencySymbol() {
        return currencySymbol;
    }

    public void setCurrencySymbol(String currencySymbol) {
        this.currencySymbol = currencySymbol;
    }

    public int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }

    public void setIndex(int index) {
        this.index = index;
    }



}
```

This is what i tried so far but this is for only products part i want to capture whole line at once

```
\\((\\d+),(\\d+\\.?\\d*?),€?(\\d+)\\)
```

Comment: What is your question?   What problems did you encounter?  How is your result different than what you expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code that lets you iterate over each token (a,b,c) and retrieve their members.
It uses [named capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html).

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public static void main(String[] args) {

        Pattern headPattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\d+).*");
        Pattern tailPattern = Pattern.compile("\\((?<p1>\\d),(?<p2>\\d+\\.\\d+),(?<p3>€\\d+)\\)");
        Matcher m1 = headPattern.matcher("80 : (1,53.38,€45) (2,88.62,€98) (3,78.48,€3) (4,72.30,€76) (5,30.18,€9)");
        Matcher m2 = tailPattern.matcher("80 : (1,53.38,€45) (2,88.62,€98) (3,78.48,€3) (4,72.30,€76) (5,30.18,€9)");

        m1.matches();
        System.out.println("p0 = " + m1.group(1));

        while(m2.find()) {
            System.out.println("token = " + m2.group());
            System.out.println("p1 = " + m2.group("p1"));
            System.out.println("p2 = " + m2.group("p2"));
            System.out.println("p3 = " + m2.group("p3"));
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi Amaud thanks, i have made little changes to make it working properly.

Comment: how can i capture "80 : " initial part of string?

Comment: @RamzanZafar I've updated my answer. Consider using https://regex101.com/ it's a very useful site when you need to debug your regex

Comment: @Amaud, i really appreciate your efforts, but i really want to achieve this with single pattern matches :-(

Comment: @RamzanZafar you always have a token (a,b,c) 4 times ? or it can vary ?

Comment: @Amaud, it can vary

Comment: Not sure if it's possible using my solution and named capturing groups. I think that you have to simply retrieve all the tokens and parse it manually